# Sequential Monte Carlo for hierarchical models

Tags: monte-carlo, hierarchical-bayesian

Does anybody know,
can Sequential Monte Carlo
be applied for multi-dimensional
problems i.e. simulating more
than 1 distribution like in
hierarchical models?
Maybe you know some following literature

Answer (score 1):

Here is a document which explain how the sequential monte carlo is generalized in multidimensional problems: http://zurich.disneyresearch.com/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/appendixA.pdf

The method is the same but the number of simulation needed evolve as a power of the dimension. So you have to use some techniques (also presented in the previous document).

Comment: That link no longer works. It can be found here now: https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~wjarosz/publications/dissertation/